# Disable the next button until the form is filled using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to disable next button until the form is filled out by the user. Full component is attached in here. I need to disable the next button. This form is build useFrom() in react-hook-from with material UI. This is integrated with API data for the address1, city, and the zip fields. Next button is process to the Payment gateway. So I need to disable the button until the form fields are completed. Only need to validate is all the fields are filled and once completed next is show to click.

```
  const AddressForm = ({ checkoutToken, test }) => {
  const [shippingCountries, setShippingCountries] = useState([]);
  const [shippingCountry, setShippingCountry] = useState('');
  const [shippingSubdivisions, setShippingSubdivisions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingSubdivision, setShippingSubdivision] = useState('');
  const [shippingOptions, setShippingOptions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingOption, setShippingOption] = useState('');
  const methods = useForm();

  const fetchShippingCountries = async (checkoutTokenId) => {
    const { countries } = await commerce.services.localeListShippingCountries(checkoutTokenId);

    setShippingCountries(countries);
    setShippingCountry(Object.keys(countries)[0]);
  };

  const fetchSubdivisions = async (countryCode) => {
    const { subdivisions } = await commerce.services.localeListSubdivisions(countryCode);

    setShippingSubdivisions(subdivisions);
    setShippingSubdivision(Object.keys(subdivisions)[0]);
  };

  const fetchShippingOptions = async (checkoutTokenId, country, stateProvince = null) => {
    const options = await commerce.checkout.getShippingOptions(checkoutTokenId, { country, region: stateProvince });

    setShippingOptions(options);
    setShippingOption(options[0].id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingCountry) fetchSubdivisions(shippingCountry);
  }, [shippingCountry]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingSubdivision) fetchShippingOptions(checkoutToken.id, shippingCountry, shippingSubdivision);
  }, [shippingSubdivision]);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Shipping address</Typography>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) => test({ ...data, shippingCountry, shippingSubdivision, shippingOption }))}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <FormInput required name="firstName" label="First name" />
            <FormInput required name="lastName" label="Last name" />
            <FormInput required name="address1" label="Address line 1" />
            <FormInput required name="email" label="Email" />
            <FormInput required name="city" label="City" />
            <FormInput required name="zip" label="Zip / Postal code" />
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Country</InputLabel>
              <Select value={shippingCountry} fullWidth onChange={(e) => setShippingCountry(e.target.value)}>
                {Object.entries(shippingCountries).map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name })).map((item) => (
                  <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                    {item.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Subdivision</InputLabel>
              <Select value={shippingSubdivision} fullWidth onChange={(e) => setShippingSubdivision(e.target.value)}>
                {Object.entries(shippingSubdivisions).map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name })).map((item) => (
                  <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                    {item.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Options</InputLabel>
              <Select value={shippingOption} fullWidth onChange={(e) => setShippingOption(e.target.value)}>
                {shippingOptions.map((sO) => ({ id: sO.id, label: `${sO.description} - (${sO.price.formatted_with_symbol})` })).map((item) => (
                  <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                    {item.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <Button component={Link} variant="contained" to="/cart" color="secondary">Back to Cart</Button>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">Next</Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: are you using useForm() from react-hook-form?

Comment: Yes. `import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';`

Comment: This is my first attempt in functional component. I need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a valid function as mentioned before

```
const isValid = shippingCountries && shippingCountry && shippingSubdivisions && shippingSubdivision && shippingOptions && shippingOption

<Button disabled={!isValid} />
```

As you use FormProvider and useForm() i think you use react-hook-form? If yes it is even more easy because it has an integrated validator.

For example you could use it like that

```
const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();
....

<form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) => test({ ...data, shippingCountry, shippingSubdivision, shippingOption }))}>
 <FormInput {...register("firstName, {required: true})}  />
</form
```

With setValue you can set the values of the form from external (for example your useEffect function)

```
setValue([{ firstName: name }, { secondOption: option }]);
```

Comment: ref={register({ required: true })} do i need to add same for all the form fields?

Comment: correct, inside the brackets you can define the validator. You could also define other validators like maxLeght, min, max etc. You can see more at the documentation under validators => https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Applyvalidation

Answer (score 0):

reference code:

<Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" **disabled={!this.state.shippingCountry || !this.state.shippingSubdivision || ...}**>Next

PS: you can have a function which return true or false for the above and then enable...

Comment: Can you explain this solution with full code. I tried but frustrated. That would be very helpful.

Comment: `render() {
    const enableButton =
    this.state.shippingCountry.length > 0 &&
    this.state.shippingDivision.length > 0 &&
      this.state.shippingOption.length > 0;`    Then replace button with `<button disabled={!enableButton}>Next</button>`